# Sitecore: TreelistEx with add item

Tags: sitecore, treelist, fieldtype

I need a sitecore field like TreelistEx with the ability to add items without leaving the page. ( Parameters to create a new object would depend on the item template it uses etc... )

Does anyone know if such a field has already been created and is available online ?

( I'm using sitecore 8 Update 1 )

Answer (score 1):

This module does something similar: https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Inline_Item_List_Field.aspx?sc_lang=en

However it was developed for Sitecore 6.x, so it properly wont work on Sitecore 8. At least not without adjustments.